# Obter multiplos valores checkbox tag

Tags: javascript, xml, checkbox

Estou exibindo uma tabela com dados vindos de um `xml`, para isso estou percorrendo o array `@ag` e montando os elementos de cada linha. Cada linha tem um `check_box_tag` para selecionar os elementos que se deseja excluir.

Agora o que eu preciso é a cada linha selecionada extrair dois elementos, que seriam código de identificação e data, pois deletar eu eu preciso dar request com esses dois dados. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo extrair duas colunas ao clicar no `check_box_tag`.

Tenho um função em javascript para armazenar os elementos selecionados em um array Eu também teria que alterar essa função para armazenar em um array multidimensional. A minha duvida principal agora é como extrair essas duas colunas ao clicar no `check_box_tag`.

Loop para exibir o conteúdo vindo do `xml`:

```
<% @ag.each do |x|  %>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        <%= check_box_tag "#{x[0]}", 0, false, :name=> "chk_del", :onclick => "MultiSelectIDs('chk_del');" %>
         </td>
        <% x.each do |y|  %>  
            <td align="center"><%= y%></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>

<%= text_field_tag :selected_ids, "", :size=>100 %>
```

função javascript:

```
// Insere na textbox especificada em fieldname os ids selecionados na listagem através dos checkbox
function MultiSelectIDs(FieldName) {
    var selected_ids = new Array()
    var objCheckBoxes = document.getElementsByName(FieldName);
    for(var i = 0; i < objCheckBoxes.length; i++){
        if (objCheckBoxes[i].checked) {
            var x = selected_ids.splice(selected_ids.length,0, objCheckBoxes[i].id); 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('selected_ids').value = selected_ids.join(", ")
};
```

Obrigada!

Comment: Oi, Alessandra , bem vinda ao [pt.so]. Seria legal se colocasse um exemplo do HTML gerado e talvez criar um JSFiddle demonstrativo. Pode [edit] a pergunta sempre que tiver novas informações que acrescentar.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos imaginar que você tenha os dados com a seguinte estrutura (vou usar json por ser mais simples de escrever):

`json
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "xpto",
    "date": "2014-11-11"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "xpto2",
    "date": "2014-11-12"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "xpto3",
    "date": "2014-11-14"
}]`

Se você não tiver um formato específico de como você deve enviar a data e o identificador na request para deletar, pode fazer sem precisar de qualquer javascript, apenas montando seu checkbox para colocar ambas as informações:

Você pode colocar seu checkbox com a propriedade name com valor similar a `elements[<id>][<date>]`.
Ou ainda colocar `elements[<date>][][id]`.

Em ambos os casos sua aplicação irá receber um array multidimensional com todas as informações que você precisa.

Se você precisar de um formato específico para fazer a request, avise e podemos rever. Se precisar de exemplos de como pegar estas informações, indique qual a linguagem que você usa no backend e podemos prover algum código.